# Get facebook share/engagement count

Tags: facebook

As a feature of our site, we are allowing users to share page(s) of our site on facebook by providing share button on our site.

We are adding users encrypted login id as part of the shared url in query param. say

`www.somedomain.com/somepage.html?lid=user1`

making the share url unique to each user who shares it.

where `lid` is the parameter namd and `user1` is the encrypted loginid. we are also keeping the shared url/link in our system. So that later we can query to facebook using the url and get count of shares, likes and comments using facebook api.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=www.somedomain.com/somepage.html?lid=user1&fields=og_object{engagement}
```

We are getting count of shares, comments and likes. But when a different user shares the same url, even though the url is different say

`www.somedomain.com/somepage.html?lid=user2`

And if I query to facebook api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=www.somedomain.com/somepage.html?lid=user2&fields=og_object{engagement}
```

The count of shares, likes and comments of those two different urls (user1 and user2) are same.

If I comments on any one users share, and query on facebook api, the count increases on both apis ( for user1 and user2).

If I like on any one users share, and query on facebook api, the count increases on both apis ( for user1 and user2).

I think facebook ignores the query param `lid=user1`  & `lid=user2` as part of `id` for any share link
 and considers only the path as `id` i.e. `www.somedomain.com/somepage.html?` and counts are maintain against this `id` or path

My question is that:

1. Is it correct what I have explained above?
2. Is there any way to make same share link unique for different users? So I can get all types count of the share link of each users without conflicting each other users

Comment: I found a link from facebook-developer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#canonical which tell us that multiple urls with same content will treat as a same/single resource. So count of shares, likes and comments will be same...

Comment: _"which tell us that multiple urls with same content will treat as a same/single resource"_ - no, it doesn't say that. It says that if you have multiple URLs referring to the same content, then you should specify which one is the "main" one using og:url or canonical. If you _want_ those different URLs to represent different Open Graph objects, then include the URL parameters in og:url/canonical.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your review. I will try to implement `og:url` and check whether it fix my problem